# Getting error on launching appium on android device

Tags: android, appium

I am  trying to run  test on android mobile using appium but on excution  it fails with  below error. I am using selenium 3.141.59 along with Appium java binding 7.0.0.

> [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1545973747782 (16:09:07 GMT+1100 (AEDT))[W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Command 'java -version' exited with code 20 [W3C] atChildProcess.proc.on.code (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/teen_process/lib/exec.js:94:19) [W3C] at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13) [W3C] at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16) [W3C] at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380:11)

Comment: attaching error from appium server

Comment: [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1545973747782 (16:09:07 GMT+1100 (AEDT))[W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Command 'java -version' exited with code 20 [W3C]     atChildProcess.proc.on.code (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/teen_process/lib/exec.js:94:19)
[W3C]     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
[W3C]     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
[W3C]     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380:11)

Comment: Attach this error in the question instead of comment for better readability